# FFMpeg nVidia Turing best quality

Tags: ffmpeg, batch

I have found this line of code to convert videos to mp4 files by FFMpeg

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -c:v h264_nvenc -preset slow -profile high 
       -level 4.1 -b 1000k -rc-lookahead 32 -g 480 -bf 3 -b_ref_mode middle
       -f mp4 Turing_output_1000k.mp4
```

I've searched the documentatuionsome of the unknown parameters to get the following result

`-i` name of the input file

`-c h264_nvenc` uses nVidia encoder to get a h264 rseult

`-preset slow` high quality with 2 passes

`-profile high` not sure about that, main or high444

`-level 4.1` that's the "version" of the mp4, 4.1 could lead to issues on old players

`-b 1000k` bitrate video 1000

`-rc-lookahead 32` number of frames to look ahead not sure about that 32

`-g 480` no idea, didn't find anything on nVend doc

`-f mp4` defines the output format not sure why this must be specified

`-bf 3` 3 B-frames

`-b_ref_mode middle` not sure if this is required

---

**Question:** could anyone fill my knowledge gaps or improve this code for a quality improvement? Or even improve use the advantage of a RTX graphics card with right number of B-frames or UV 4:4:4!?

Comment: For one, bumping up the bitrate will increase "quality". But you may have to clarify what you mean by quality.

Comment: I want to use all tools from the tool box (B-Frames, 2 Pass, Lookahead,... ) and use the best settings for quality for a fixed bitrate using nVEnc.

Comment: See [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/ffmpeg/comments/anganq/sharing_hevc_nvenc_settings_for_highquality/) where the opinion is that nVEnc isn't useful for quality, except in the RTX 2000 series where it is much improved. The opinion there is that the slower CPU encoding is more precise.

Comment: A 1 megabit/s bitrate may be good for comics, but not for sports and action films, or natural documentaries. Don't expect a "4K" display quality with any MPEG4-based encoder (it may just be slighly better with opensourced WebP, or more modern codecs like proprietary HEVC). Anyway I no longer recommend any MPEG-based codec, encumbered by patents severely limiting the coder implementations.

Comment: So FFMeg is free, but it has a cost: without a paid licence, it cannot use the advanced technics that would help preserve mroe quality at the specified bitrate. That's where the encoding made with a costly RTX hardware may be better because you pay these licences with your graphics card.
Anyway, converting an AVI source (which is already based on some MPEG variant) to another MPEG format will not really benefit, it can only be used to reduce the quality to a lower bitrate, but it may add its own noise with approximation and poor choices of parameters.

Comment: Finally, don't expect increasing the quality with any reencoding. All you can do is to add new effect artefacts (like increasing contrasts, reducing "noise" by flattening...) This si what you get in many modern flat TVs that propose to "enhance" the images but in fact worsen its real quality (in terms of spacial resolution, movement, preservation of the color gamut and precision, and distortions. What you do there for images is like when processing digital audio: you just apply loose filters to create totally artificial effects.